# Issue with Excel VBA file "save as" in my user folder or network drive

Tags: vba, excel

I am having an issue saving a file via VBA in certain directories.  If I use the folder called C:\Test it works fine.  However if I try to save it to my users\me\Documents folder or a network folder, I an error.  I can normally save to my users directory or the network folder when saving directly from Excel.  The following code is what I use to create the file and then save a version before a macro runs. Is there a better way to do this to be able to at least save on the network drive?  For additional detail, I try to save to the users drive but get a Error 1004, which gives me some things to look for which I don't see.

For example I expect the path to be C:\Test\Segname.xlsx, and that works in the test directory.  Doesn't work anywhere else.   Thanks in advance.

```
Sub AddNew(NewBook As Object)
Dim newPath As Variant
Dim SegName As Variant

SegName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Range("D29").Value
newPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & SegName

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
    With NewBook
        .Title = "Calculations Output"
        .Subject = "Sales"
        .SaveAs Filename:=newPath
        .Worksheets.Add().Name = "DATA"
    End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you confirm that this is **not** [tag:excel-vba-mac] ?

Comment: It is on a Windows PC

Comment: Does `newPath = environ("USERPROFILE") & "\documents\" & SegName` work for you?

Comment: It does not, but I am suspicious my issue is with SegName. When I step through I see SegName is "empty", but just not sure why that would happen in this directory and not in C:\Test

Comment: @Vaslo So what is the value of `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Range("D29")` ?

Comment: @horst I am a moron and forgot to put a value in D29 there in that userfolder file vs the one that was in Test.  Sorry for wasting people's time.